# asp.net secure cookies

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

I want to secure my cookies, i read about "HTTPOnly" and "Secure" cookie flags for the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie.
I create new asp.net project in VS. And in fiddler in Inspectors -> raw i have:

```
Cookie: DXCurrentThemeMVC=Office2010Black; ASP.NET_SessionId=1gq0t1mi234xyljqnxrzbqfx
```

Then i modify  web.config :

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" requireSSL="true" />
    </authentication>
```

But in fiddler the same data

```
 Cookie: DXCurrentThemeMVC=Office2010Black; ASP.NET_SessionId=1gq0t1mi234xyljqnxrzbqfx
```

I think when i add
 `<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true"/>` 
i cant see cookies in fiddler, or cookies will be encrypted. Is this  correct result ? Or i have mistake somewhere?

**EDIT**

and why i dont see in fiddler

```
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=ig2fac55; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

but only cookie without set-, and secure, and HttpOnly also in firebug i see the same results

**EDIT2**
It seems like i find my problem: i host app on iis and in firebug look for cookies, and i have cookies with secure and httpOnly Flags:

```
ASP.NET_SessionId=98sfd90sdf89sd0f80s8; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  None of my cookies in Firebug show up as HttpOnly or secure.  How did you fix it?  I added the <httpCookies> line to my web.config.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at the [httpCookies Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228262(v=vs.100).aspx) session in MSDN.

**httpOnlyCookies** sets the HttpOnly flags in response header.
See [Protecting Your Cookies: HttpOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html) article.

**requireSSL** force the cookie to be transferred through a secure channel, so it's not removed and is encrypted during the transport.

Comment: First link should point here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228262(v=vs.100).aspx , I think.

Answer (score 1):

To Secure Cookies you can use **IDataProtector** to encrypt and decrypt your value

in your Class :

```
private IDataProtector dataProtector;

public HomeController(IDataProtectionProvider provider)
{
    //TODO:Set Your Private Key
    dataProtector = provider.CreateProtector("YourPrivateKey");
}
```

you can than use it in your methods :

```
public IActionResult SetNewCookie(string key,string value) {

        var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
        cookieOptions.Secure = true;
        cookieOptions.HttpOnly = true;

        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append(key,dataProtector.Protect(value),cookieOptions);
        return View(nameof(Index));
}
```

and at the end to decript the cookie value we can use :

```
dataProtector.Unprotect(value);
```

I'm Also using "**CookieOptions**" and setting secure and httpOnly true for more security (it will be harder to get the cookies when you're using third party software)